# Convert the following SWITCH statement into an IF...ELSE statement

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

b)  Convert the following switch statement into an if…else statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char option;
    int a;
    printf("a.Addition\n b.Subtraction\n c.Multiplication\n d.Division\n");
    printf("Choose your option : ");
    scanf("%c",&option);

    switch(option)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'A': a=20+10;
        printf("Addition process result:%d",a);
        break;
    case 'b':
    case 'B': a=20-10;
        printf("Subtraction process result:%d",a);
        break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C': a=20*10;
        printf("Multiplication process result:%d",a);
        break;
    case 'd':
    case 'D': a=20/10;
        printf("Division process result:%d",a);
        break;
    default: printf("Invalid option");
    }
    printf("\nEnd of program");

}
```

How do I convert it from SWITCH to IF...ELSE? 
This is a revision question for my exam
Thank You

Comment: Solve it, post it and we'll discuss this.

Comment: `This is a revision question for my exam` -- Thanks for being brutally honest.

Comment: revision question? Then might be discussed during class ;)

Comment: erm..this question is for us to practice....nvr discuss in the class

Comment: IF...ELSE not discussed in the class.. I don't believe this!

Comment: Did your teacher really give you code that has `void main()` ??? They should be fired.

Comment: If this code was given to you by your teacher, I'd consider it a good thin if I flunked his exam, because _my_ code will at least work

Answer (score 9):

A `switch` statement can be thought of as a series of `if`/`else` clauses. Here's an example which should help you to solve your specific question:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        foo();
        break;       

    case 3:
    case 4:
        bar();
        break;       

    default:
        blech();
        break;       
}
```

becomes:

```
if (x == 1 || x == 2)         // case 1:
{                             // case 2:
    foo();
}
else if (x == 3 || x == 4)    // case 3:
{                             // case 4:
    bar();
}
else                          // default:
{
    blech();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(option == 'a' ||option == 'A')   //checks if option value is 'a' or 'A',in switch case you use case:a,and case:b
  {
   a=20+10;       
   printf("Addition process result:%d",a);
   }
else if(option == 'b' ||option == 'B')    
   {
    a=20-10;
    printf("Subtraction process result:%d",a);
    }
else if(option == 'c' ||option == 'C')    
    {
     a=20*10;
     printf("Multiplication process result:%d",a);
    }
else if(option == 'd' ||option == 'D')    
    {
     a=20/10;
     printf("Division process result:%d",a);
    }
else
    {
      printf("Invalid option");
    }
```

**How Did I Transformed:**

1:changed all `cases` in  to conditional statements in `if`

example:

```
switch(option)
{
  case 'a':
  case 'A':some statement;
         break;
}
```

to

```
   if(option == 'a' || option == 'A')
   {

    some statement;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't paste complete solutions to homework or study problems - give hints, guidance, etc, to help the OP solve the problem - they will learn much more that way. Also: formatting.

Comment: @PaulR :Sure, am editing

Comment: i want to know who downvoted this answer ????

Comment: @PaulR :  did i did anything wrong,who downvoted my answer

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct, but the rules of the site don't recommend to simply solve somebody's homework. So, somebody COULD downvote for this. I have seen minuses I couldn't understand at all. I'll put a plus, don't worry. But beware, very often when you are trying to get info why they are minusing you, you get even more minuses. Really, I can't understand your innocence in that question at your rep level. It seems my java/android community is much more severe that your html/javascript one. And the C/C++ community IS strict, be sure!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char option;
    int a;
    printf("a.Addition\n b.Subtraction\n c.Multiplication\n d.Division\n");
    printf("Choose your option : ");
    scanf("%c",&option);

    if (option == 'a' || option == 'A') {
        printf("Addition process result:%d",a);
    }
    elseif (option == 'b' || option == 'B') {
        printf("Subtraction process result:%d",a);
    }
    elseif (option == 'c' || option == 'C') {
        printf("Multiplication process result:%d",a);
    }
    elseif (option == 'd' || option == 'D') {
        printf("Division process result:%d",a);
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid option");
    }
    printf("\nEnd of program");

}
```

This is the solution of your question.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile at my m/c.. says elseif not found?

Comment: -1: does not even compile, and even after fixing the syntax errors it would not behave in the same way as the OP's code.

Comment: +1 for your try though. Make sure you post correct and compiled code.

Comment: @SajadLfc what you have done? I dont know..

Comment: @Digital_Reality : somebody down voted my answer without reason man

Comment: Oh yes.. just saw that. Trust me.. I did not!

Comment: @SajadLfc some people simply want to get a silver medal for voting. So they look posts one after another and vote in random manner. Some people could have bad mood... It happens. It is strange that with you rep you haven't seen this before. And where is your answer?

Comment: @Gangnus: below is my answer.!! and Yah you are right..!!